# nested if statement in one line

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
if(something.food == true){
  if(something.food.fruit == 'apple' ||  something.food.fruit == 'mango'){
//do something
}
}
```

this is clear where food must be true later check it's child object, but how to write this in one line? I mean with single if.

Comment: `if (something.food == true && (something.food.fruit == 'apple' ||  something.food.fruit == 'mango')) {
//do something
}`

Comment: What do you think? What did you try? What does logic tell you?

Comment: It's all about implicit conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `something.food` is `true` then it can not be an object containing fields as well. Though your current check does check for a ["truthy"](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) value, it reads quite strange (thanks for pointing this out [T. J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder)). Instead you should just leave out the `== true` part.

The resulting check is:

```
if (something.food && (something.food.fruit == 'apple' || something.food.fruit == 'mango') {
        //do something
}
```

Comment: `== true` *does* check if it's "truthy". (It's a silly way to check, but...) `=== true` wouldn't, but `== true` does.

Comment: You are right, I'll change my answer to reflect this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

That's all

```
if(something.food && (something.food.fruit == 'apple' ||  something.food.fruit == 'mango')) {

    //do something

}
```

As a petition in the comments, I will explain that.

First we check `something.food` without `== true` because we need to check if it exists. Then wrap the rest of code into parenthesis and the expression will run ok

Comment: A *useful* answer *explains*, it doesn't just dump code.

Comment: This code is self-explaining. With 6 years old, I learn in the class of Maths the parenthesis order of operations. I can explain what I make here, but it's aproximately as explain how to speak

Comment: Answer edited with explanation. Maybe it's not the best explanation of the world, but I don't know how to explain that simple thing